# Problema con array_search en PHP y algoritmo que te dice si una clave primaria está en un array o no

Tags: php, mysql, sql

A ver, estoy haciendo un script que recibe como parámetros dos matrices llenos de arrays que corresponden a todos los datos de dos tablas MySQL de la misma base de datos del mismo servidor. Es decir, que en la matriz A, el array 0 es un registro de la tabla A, el array 1 un registro de la tabla A y así. El caso es que tengo el siguiente código:

```
function comprobarCambiosPedidosEnPedidosRemoto($datosPedidos, $datosPedidosRemoto){
    
            //Creo un array para tener los datos que difieren entre ambas tablas
            $registrosDiferentes = [];
            $encontrado=false;

            


            // Recorrer arreglo de resultados Pedidos
            foreach($datosPedidos as $idPedido) {
                // echo "<pre>";
                // var_dump($idPedido);
                // echo "</pre>";
                //var_dump($idPedido["IdPedido"]);

            $index=array_search($idPedido["IdPedido"], $datosPedidosRemoto);

            if($index!==false){
                var_dump($index);
            } else {
                echo "No funciona";
            }
        
            // var_dump($registrosDiferentes);
            //
            }
}
```

Tengo dos dudas. Si hago un var_dump de $idPedido me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
array(6) {
  ["IdPedido"]=>
  string(9) " 432442-A"
  ["numeroseguimiento"]=>
  string(8) "543542-A"
  ["Estado"]=>
  NULL
  ["cod_pedido_prov"]=>
  NULL
  ["agencia_prov"]=>
  NULL
  ["url_tracking"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Con lo cual, viendo eso, pienso... Igual sería mejor en el foreach meter para la búsqueda con array_search $idpedido["idpedido"]; de la siguiente forma:

```
$index=array_search($idPedido["IdPedido"], $datosPedidosRemoto);
```

Sin embargo, cuando yo hago eso, ocurre lo siguiente:

```
No funciona
```

Es decir, se me mete en el else (no sé por qué) y me hace eso constantemente. Si le cambio el código del array_search:

```
$index=array_search($idPedido, $datosPedidosRemoto);
```

pues me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
int(0) int(1) int(2) int(3) int(4)...
```

Es decir, cuándo hago el array_search con $idpedido me devuelve lo correcto (o eso creo, porque no sé cómo metiéndole el $idpedido sabe realmente que quiero coger $idpedido["IdPedido"] y no cualquier otro valor de dicho array) pero cuando lo hago con $idpedido["IdPedido"] que es el valor exacto que quiero coger no me funciona. ¿Alguien me puede explicar en qué estoy fallando? Porque no acabo de comprenderlo y no sé si me está funcionando como quiero o no (no sé si el índice que me devuelve es realmente del IdPedido o de cualquier otro valor del array de la matriz)? Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Pregutna ... Cuando consultas tus datos los estas trabajando con **mysqli_fetch_assoc** o **fetch array** si es asi estos convierten lo que traes en tu consulta en un arreglo asociativo y es mas facil manipularlos, si estas trabajndo asi, lo que yo te recomendaria es que hagas un while y dentro de ese while busques lo que tengas que buscar

Comment: Los estoy sacando con mysqli_fetch_assoc.

Comment: Perfecto a tu resultado recorrelo con un while ejemplo while($resultado){} estarias diciendo mientras halla datos  en resultado haces lo que tengas que hacer, en este caso buscar contenido de $resultado en otro array, recuerda que es un array asociatio ejemplo $resultado['id']

Comment: Vale, sólo una pregunta... ¿Por temas de rendimiento, no es mejor en este caso usar array_search()?

Comment: Aplica la tecnica de "divide y venceras" primero logra el objetivo que quieres realizar, despues podrias mejorar tu codigo en temas de rendimiento.

Comment: Me sigue pasando algo parecido. Si muestro $datosPedidos me devuelve la matriz entera, pero si le digo que me muestre $datosPedidos["IdPedido"], me dice que undefinex index. Y, he probado tanto con comillas simples como con dobles. ¿A qué se puede deber el error? No comprendo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrias poner el var_dump() en ambas matrices para ver que es lo que contiene cada una y poder realizar pruebas.

Comment: Lo he hecho y me he dado cuenta de que al valor se accede de la siguiente forma $datosPedidos[0]["IdPedido]. El problema es que ahora no sé cómo buscar los valores en la otra matriz. Necesitaría hacerlo dinámico de esta forma $datosPedidos[$i]["IdPedido] pero el caso es que... Un for no creo que sea adecuado porque el registro X en la tabla A puede estar en la posición 100 y en la tabla B en la posición 500; un while en este caso no sé cómo usarlo porque debe ser dinámico (con el $i) y lo que más adecuado veo es el array_search pero tampoco lo acabo de ver claro. ¿Qué me aconsejas?

Comment: muestrame que es lo que te arroja al hacer var_dump() a datosPedidosRemoto para poder yo poder hacer pruebas

Comment: Arroja exactamente lo mismo que tengo apuntado arriba como var_dump de $idPedido. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema que yo veo es que `$datosPedidos` y `$datosPedidosRemoto` contienen en su interior arreglos, es decir "Es un arreglo de arreglos" te muestro un ejemplo practico para que puedas recorrer de manera correcta estos arreglos.

1.- Tenemos el primer array `$datosPedidos` el cual luce de esta manera:

```
$datosPedidos = array([
  "IdPedido" => "432442-A",
  "numeroseguimiento" => "543542-A",
  "Estado" => NULL,
  "cod_pedido_prov" => NULL,
  "agencia_prov" => NULL,
  "url_tracking" =>  NULL
],
[
  "IdPedido" => "432442-B",
  "numeroseguimiento" => "543542-A",
  "Estado" => NULL,
  "cod_pedido_prov" => NULL,
  "agencia_prov" => NULL,
  "url_tracking" =>  NULL
]
);
```

2.- Tenemos el segundo array `$datosPedidosRemoto` el cual luce de esta manera:

```
$datosPedidosRemoto = array([
  "IdPedido" => "432442-B",
  "numeroseguimiento" => "543542-A",
  "Estado" => NULL,
  "cod_pedido_prov" => NULL,
  "agencia_prov" => NULL,
  "url_tracking" =>  NULL,
],
[
  "IdPedido" => "432442-B",
  "numeroseguimiento" => "543542-A",
  "Estado" => NULL,
  "cod_pedido_prov" => NULL,
  "agencia_prov" => NULL,
  "url_tracking" =>  NULL,
]
);
```

3.- Tendrias que recorrer ambos para poder obtener su `Key` quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach($datosPedidos as $idPedido){
    foreach($datosPedidosRemoto as $idPedidoRemoto){

       if($idPedido['IdPedido'] == $idPedidoRemoto['IdPedido']){
           echo "SE ENCONTRARON CONINIDENCIAS";
       }
    }
}
```

4.- Nota que tenemos un **for anidado** y ahora si podemos buscar lo que hay en `$idPedido['IdPedido']` en el otro arreglo `$idPedidoRemoto['IdPedido']`

5.- Intentalo y me dices que tal.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias :)